# Xamarin google login

Tags: xamarin.android, google-oauth

I'm trying to log the user into google and get a UserCredential for the youtube Api. I've made many research but all the informations i've found are outdated or arn't working on xamarin. Can somebody send a link to an updated documentation whitch work on xamarin android, an exemple (like a github) or describe here how to do it.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you refer to this example : https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/google-services/SigninQuickstart/ ?

Comment: This is outdated and the sample never log on.